# Install4j task/action for all users

Tags: install4j

I need to know if there is any task/action that will be trigger for all users.
[on Windows machines]

The action needs to run ONLY at install time not upon running the executable/launcher.

Keep in mind that users can be added later.

Comment: What does "triggered for all users" mean? You mean execute something once when those users log on the next time?

Comment: @IngoKegel Yes, something that executes ONLY one time after an (re)install (ex: to trigger an import routine)

Comment: There is no such feature in install4j. You would have to handle that in your launcher.

Comment: @IngoKegel indeed. I'm making a solution based on Java's Preferences. The installer only creates a time stamp and stores in the Preferences and application simply check against that time stamp and takes the necessary actions.

Comment: It would be a useful action to have. I've added this as a feature request to our issue tracker.